# SNMP Oid Conversion Difference Between RHEL 6.3 and Solaris 10

Tags: c++, snmp, rhel, net-snmp, solaris-10

I've been stuck at an issue of SNMP OID conversion for couple of days. We have a cpp program to poll cable modem, nowadays, we ported this application from Solaris 10 to Linux 6.3, everything works fine until we found that it got some SNMP trap problem on RHEL 6.3 platform.
After some investigation, it turns out that the same OID has been converted into different strings for these 2 OS platform, like:

snmpTrapOID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.4998.1.1.10.1.0.16

**on Solaris 10:** it is interpreted as ***cmResetMacAddress***: *0015CF5B6B0B* (mac address), however, **on RHEL 6.3:**, it shows ***enterprises***: *0015CF5B6B0B*

Still no clue how to go ahead and how to fix this issue as we didn't do any changes for business logic like how to convert OID, only update some system calls to make this program can be ran on Linux, which is has nothing to do with SNMP stuff, it would be appreciated for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP OID to name conversion requires proper MIB documents to be available.

4998 is the enterprise ID for Cadant Inc.,

http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers

So in your case you need to check where you put Cadant's MIB documents on Solaris, and then move them to RHEL (make sure you put them to the correct place).

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, Lex, and for this part, I've made them the same settings for both of platforms.
Indeed, I found when I start our cpp application on RHEL 6.3, it prompts an error that "Did not find 'IANAipRouteProtocol' in module #-1", which didn't occur on Solaris. I am not sure if this is the case, but I am digging :)

Comment: It is very likely to be the cause of the problem, as `IANA-RTPROTO-MIB` which contains `IANAipRouteProtocol` is one of the core MIB documents, that should be loaded properly ahead of other documents. Compare the copies of MIB documents on the two machines and see if there is anything wrong with the version on RHEL side.

Comment: For the mib folder, which we put all mib we need and process by our cpp application, they are exactly same between Solaris and Linux. However, for the version of net-snmp, ya, you're right, they are different, Solaris is using v5.0 but RHEL is v5.5, I am not sure if that is the root cause but I will try to verify this and, surely, keep you updated.
For the verification, what I can do is replace the v5.5 with v5.0 on RHEL, do you have any other ideas? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For temp fix, I get the value of "**enterprises**" directly to resolve this problem on Linux. I know this is not a good way, but it works for these couple weeks and no problem raised.